# adding Xaxis data in each series highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

the chart shows 3 series with data , however i want to add Xaxis data, the code for this is:

```
 xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov',     'Dec']
    },
```

but how will i add it to my code, where i have used a function. i want to add a categories with data['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr] etc...

into this code:

```
   $(".test").change(function() {
     var value = this.getAttribute("value");
     while (chart.series.length > 0) {
        chart.series[0].remove(true);
    }
    if (value == 'a') {
        chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "data" });

        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall11',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#08F',  
            data:[100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200]             
        });      

        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall2',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#808000',  
            data:[100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200]             
        });                      
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall3',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#FFA500',  
            data:[100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200]             
        });
```

each series should have a diffrent Xaxis...

jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VnCgx/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add it like

```
 chart.xAxis[0].update({categories: ['Jan', 'Feb'], etc
```

the whole code in below

```
if (value == 'a') {
        chart.xAxis[0].update({categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',     'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']});
        chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({ text: "kHw" });
//            if(chart.series.length>=2)
//                chart.series[1].remove();
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall11',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#08F',  
            data:[100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]             
        });      
//            chart.series[1].remove();
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall2',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#808000',  
            data:[100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]             
        });                      
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'Rainfall3',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#FFA500',  
            data:[100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]             
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use setCategories http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories()

Answer (score 0):

simply add x-axis values as

```
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
         xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
    });
```

refer this.
http://jsfiddle.net/Bhaarat/VnCgx/5/